# Error installing Savanna - Command not found

Tags: 12.04, openstack

I have followed tutorial from here to install OpenStack from [here](http://ilearnstack.com/2013/04/26/setting-up-a-single-node-openstack-environment/),

Now I want to install `Savanna`, I am following from [here](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/sahara/userdoc/installation.guide.html)

But when I execute this command

```
savanna-venv/bin/python savanna-venv/bin/savanna-db-manage --config-file savanna-venv/etc/savanna.conf upgrade head
```

it says `Command not found`!

How to solve the problem?

Another question is that can anyone guide me to configure `savanna.conf` file?

Comment: You say that you want to install `savanna`, but you have given link to installation of `sahara`. Or do you want to install `sahara`?

Answer (score 0):

The docs you've posted are for Sahara development version. It will be released along with OpenStack Icehouse release in two weeks from now (April 17 is the target). Currently these docs might be misleading.

Use the following guide to install Savanna 0.3 on OpenStack Havanna:
http://savanna.readthedocs.org/en/0.3/